# can any body please tell me how to increase my website loading speed?

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed

Hello every one please tell me ho can i increase my website loading speed or how can i decrease number of http request on my web page

Here is my website [Alpha Click](http://www.alphaclick.in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Bundle your javascript in one file, and bundle and minimize your css in one file to make less requests
- Use image sprites

Answer (score 0):

Consider avoiding viewport values that prevent users from resizing documents.

Section lacks heading. Consider using h2-h6 elements to add identifying headings to all sections.

From line 12, column 2814; to line 12, column 2851

Also Bundle your javascript in one file as answer 1

JohnC

Comment: This could help

Comment: The following images are resized in HTML or CSS. Serving scaled images could save 199.0KiB (81% reduction).

https://www.alphaclick.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/reflogs.jpg is resized in HTML or CSS from 800x600 to 347x260. Serving a scaled image could save 87.9KiB (81% reduction).https://www.alphaclick.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/publicdimand-featured-imaage.pngis resized in HTML or CSS from 800x600 to 347x260. Serving a scaled image could save 71.4KiB    https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.alphaclick.in/mNTdGNOE